# nginx tries to serve .rss/.json itself rather than letting rails/unicorn serve it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

My rails app runs perfectly fine in production using nginx and unicorn except for one thing:
Requesting `/articles.rss` and `/articles.json` leads to a 404 with an error in the nginx logs that the requested file doesn't exist. Requesting e.g. `/articles?format=rss` works. So it looks like the *.rss* leads nginx to think this is a static file rather than dynamically generated content. In development (using the builtin server of rails) this works fine.

I use the [h5bp config files for nginx](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx), here's my site configuration (domain name replaced):

```
# www to non-www redirect -- duplicate content is BAD:
# https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/5370479476dceae7cc3ea105946536d6bc0ee468/.htaccess#L362
# Choose between www and non-www, listen on the *wrong* one and redirect to
# the right one -- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name
upstream app {
  server unix:/var/www/rails-cms/shared/tmp/sockets/rails-cms.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  # don't forget to tell on which port this server listens
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  server_name www.<my domain>;

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 $scheme://<my domain>$request_uri;
}

server {
  # listen [::]:80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  # listen 80 accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  # listen [::]:80 deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 deferred; # for Linux
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name <my domain>;

  # Path for static files
  root /var/www/rails-cms/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  # Include the basic h5bp config set
  include h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you include `h5bp/basic.conf` file which in turn includes `h5bp/location/expires.conf` file. Take a look at the latter file's contents:

```
# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  access_log logs/static.log;
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
  expires 1h;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

See? the first `location` intercepts `.json` requests, and the second one - `.rss` requests, so your app never catches these requests.

If you want your app to handle these requests, you should either refuse `h5bp` at all, or just comment out abovementioned `location`s.

In both cases your app should send cache headers itself, if you want it of course.

***Edit:***

But since your `json` and `rss` contents are dynamically generated, I would not recommend using cache headers.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Commenting those sections out worked! I already looked at them before, however I thought that just defining caching behaviour wouldn't affect whether nginx or unicorn would serve it.

Comment: welcome! yes, this is how Nignx works. if some `location` catches the request, the another `location` can't do it after that (if it is not declared inside the first location, i.e. "nested" location)